# How to Get Youtube Vidoe Publish Date Without use API in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have requirement where I have excel sheet contains youtube URLs. I want to fetch this URLs and validate with youtube. I want below information. - Whether URL/video is exist. - Date created/updated. - Whether URL/video was exist but deleted now. If so, deleted date.

Am Developing windows application using vb.net without using youtube API.

Can somebody please help me out on this.

Thanks

Comment: You mean without using any API at all? If the video is gone how would you know when it was deleted if not using an API? Of course you can tell if it's deleted or not but i don't think you can tell when without using the API. What's the reason you don't want to use the API?

Comment: Hi Devcon,Thank you Advance.  My client requirment is dnt use API, want to know 1. Video Published date, 2. is Video delete or Not.

Comment: For the Published date you have to read the data in the "upload-info" div, if that exists then the video exists. if you check innerhtml of "date style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer" you will get "Published on Feb 8, 2019"

Comment: You could load the YouTube Video hidden in a Webbrowser Control and filter its elements looking in the JavaScript or HTML for the upload Date.

Comment: i will try, Thank you Mr Loastaub